# How to hide or show a content of a python function on qweb report depend on condition?

Tags: python, odoo-9, qwebview

im trying to re design my Odoo 9 qweb report. that inherited sale_order_report. I have created some python function that have been called on the qweb. Now i would like to hide that content of the python function depend on conditions. Please take a moment to read my code bellow and help me to point out the specifics way to solve the problem?

```
@api.multi
def handle_detail(self, order_line):
    dict_item = {}
    for line in order_line:
        for key in 
        quantity_extra = int(line.quantity_extra)
        if quantity_extra not in dict_item.keys():
                dict_item[quantity_extra].append(line.lng)
            else:
                dict_item[quantity_extra] = [line.lng]
result = []
total = 0.0
for item in dict_item.keys():
    lst_ing = dict_item[item]
    if len(lst_ing) > 1:
        result.append(
            '( %s ) x %s' % (' + '.join([str(lng) for lng in lst_ing]),
                             str(item)))
        total += (sum(lst_ing) * item)
    else:
        result.append('%s x %s' % (str(lst_ing[0]), str(item)))
        total += (lst_ing[0] * item)
return result, total
```

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

surround the code in the template by a t-if statement like this

```
 <t t-if="condition"> <!-- if the condition is true the contenant is shown -->
       <....code that calls the method and show the value on the template />
  </t>
```